# Elegant way to get minimum between two prices while throwing out non-positive values

Tags: php, validation, floating-point, minimum

Currently, I'm doing this in several steps, and I wonder if there's a better way.

Here's how I'm doing it.

1. Check if the values are both non-numeric or both non-positive numbers. If they are, throw an error and exit. This guarantees at least 1 positive number.
2. Cast both values to `(float)`. If one of the two was non-numeric, it should be 0 now.
3. If num1 is zero, use num2. Else If num2 is zero, use num1. Else use `min(num1,num2)`

---

```
// 1
if(!(is_numeric($num1) && $num1 >0) && !(is_numeric($num2) && $num2 >0) ) {
    die('error');
}
// at least one is a positive number. Other could be a different number or not numeric.

// 2
$num1 = (float)$num1;
$num2 = (float)$num2;
// now both are numbers, at least one is positive

// 3
if($num1 <= 0) {
    $price = $num2;
} elseif($num2 <= 0) {
    $price = $num1;
} else {
    $price = min($num1,$num2);
}
// finally we have the price
```

**I am using php5**

Comment: Your code block as not formatting as you expected because of the list-item formatting the preceded it.  I've added `---` to create a horizontal rule and _break_ the list formatting.  Otherwise, you could have added 4 more spaces to each line of code, but that would have nested your snippet in the 3rd list item.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you convert the numbers to floats before comparing them to `0`; this will force non-numerics to `0` and then you can filter out the negatives, the original zeros, and the converted zeros in one step.  If there are no qualifying prices, make an early return.  If at least one qualifying price exists, return the lower of the two.

As a matter of convenient, simplified, DRY programming, I am batching the values into an array for swift handling.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/653oT))

```
function newGetMinPrice($nums) {
    $nums = array_filter($nums, function($v){ return (float)$v > 0;});  // convert to float and check if greater than 0
    if (empty($nums)) {
        return 'error';  // if no qualifying prices, return error
    }
    return min($nums);  // return the lowest qualifying price
}

$tests = [[0, .1], [1, 'foo'], [.24, -.25], [3, 3], ['foo', 'bar'], [-0, 0.1], [90, -90], [0, 0], [1, 1]];
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "new: {$test[0]} -vs- {$test[1]} = ",newGetMinPrice($test), "\n";
}
```

Output: (identical performance as your posted snippet

```
new: 0 -vs- 0.1 = 0.1
new: 1 -vs- foo = 1
new: 0.24 -vs- -0.25 = 0.24
new: 3 -vs- 3 = 3
new: foo -vs- bar = error
new: 0 -vs- 0.1 = 0.1
new: 90 -vs- -90 = 90
new: 0 -vs- 0 = error
new: 1 -vs- 1 = 1
```

...or you could condense like:

```
$nums = array_filter($nums, function($v){ return (float)$v > 0;});  // convert to float and check if greater than 0
return empty($nums) ? 'error' : min($nums);
```

---

p.s. you could also generate a battery of conditions if you don't want to use `array_filter()` ...though I don't think it is any prettier than your original snippet.

```
$num1 = max(0, (float)$num1);
$num2 = max(0, (float)$num2);
if ($num1 === 0) {                    // bad num1
    if ($num2 === 0) {                // bad num2
        return 'error';              // send error
    }
    return $num2;                    // send good num2
}
// 1 is good...
if ($num2 === 0 || $num1 <= $num2) {  // bad num2 or num1 better than num2
    return $num1;                    // send good/better num1
}
return $num2;                        // both num1 and num2 are good, send num2
```

or without declaring `newGetMinPrice()`:

```
$nums = array((float)$num1,(float)$num2);  // force input values to float values
$nums = array_filter($nums, function($v){return $v > 0;});  // check if greater than 0
if (empty($nums)) {
    die('error');
} else {
    $price = min($nums);  // declare lowest qualifying price
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fCJ3T)

Comment: @Buttle If you have any fringe cases that my solution fails to handle properly, please offer me the input data and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: @Buttle which subversion of php5 are you running?  I suppose that will determine if I've used any components that are too modern in my solution/demo.